# How do I add a method to an existing object?

Tags: javascript

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
};



//Now create three instances of Person with data you make up

var p1 = new Person('Aaron', 32);
var p2 = new Person('Casey', 30);
var p3 = new Person('Greg',31);



//Now add a sayName method on your Person class that will alert the name of whatever Person instance called it.
```

I'm not sure how to add a method to an existing class. I'm new to JavaScript. I understand how to add new properties but not new functions.

Answer (score 7):

Add the method to the `Person`  prototype chain.

```
Person.prototype.sysName = function() {
    return console.log(this.name);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var Person = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
 alert(this.name)
}

var p1 = new Person('Aaron', 32);

p1.sayName()
```

You can define Methods in using `prototype`

`Person.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using prototyping you can add a method to an object though doing: `myObject.prototype.myMethod = function(){ ... }`

```
Person.prototype.sayName = function(){
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

Another way can be directly adding it on the creation of `Person`, just note the method is duplicated for each instance in this case:

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  this.sayName = function() {
      console.log(this.name);
  }
};
```

Comment: Using the second option, will create a new function for every instance. Which is not recommended.

Comment: @Mohamed-Ted I'm aware of that, was about to add it in as an edit. Although there is not a significant difference in most cases unless there are many thousands of instances being created.

Answer (score 0):

`Person.prototype.sayName = function() { 
  console.log(this.name)
}`

you can add a prototype function to the Person class and then each person has access to the function.

Comment: This is literally the same answer everyone else posted.