# How to pass a method as parameter value in javascript object property?

Tags: javascript

I have a object like this

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function () {
    //upload process
  }
};
```

from another method, I can create a object of this class and pass parameter like

```
myDropzone = new dropzoneForm();
myDropzone.addRemoveLinks = false; //something like this works perfectly.
```

But I need to achieve another thing like

```
myDropzone.removedFile: function(){
//do something}
```

How can I achieve this, please suggest me.

Comment: Hi Sam, please try to rephrase your questions of what you are having issues with. Your question is not 100% clear. What is the issue exactly with removeFile you cannot make happen? Maybe give an example of what you've tried?

Comment: You do not need to do `new`. `dropzoneForm`  is a object literal and not a class. Either set it as a constructor or directly consume the object

Comment: May be this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39419794/4903314 https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522017/4903314

Comment: Something like. `myDropzone.prototype.removedFile: function(){
//do something}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add this method to dropzoneForm use prototype but if you want to add this method to myDropzone you can do this easily :

```
myDropzone.removedFile = function(){
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prototype to add method to your Object

```
dropzoneForm.prototype.removedFile = function(){
    // do something
}
var inst = new dropzoneForm();
inst.removedFile();
```